# How to Identify MySQL Trigger Operation

Tags: mysql, triggers

In Oracle, when writing a unique trigger that handles INSERT, UPDATE OR DELETE operations, when can detect which operation is being executed using this technique, called '[Conditional Predicates](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/triggers.htm#LNPLS750)'

```
create trigger sample_trigger
    before insert or update
    on sample_table
    for each row
begin
    case
        when inserting then
            --do something
        when updating then
            --do something
    end case;
end;
```

Does MySQL 5.6 provides any technique that allows me to do the same? I wouldn't like to write three distinct triggers only to differentiate which operating is being executed. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

No. In MySQL (even in 8.0) triggers can only be called for one type of operation, `INSERT`, `UPDATE` or `DELETE`. From the [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-trigger.html), the syntax for `CREATE TRIGGER` is:

> ```
> CREATE
>     [DEFINER = { user | CURRENT_USER }]
>     TRIGGER trigger_name
>     trigger_time trigger_event
>     ...
> ```

and `trigger_event` may only be one of `INSERT`, `UPDATE` or `DELETE`:

> ```
> trigger_event: { INSERT | UPDATE | DELETE }
> ```

So given that there is no scope to call a trigger for different operations, there is no need to have the conditional predicates you describe.

What you could do instead in put your trigger code into a stored procedure, and then call that with a parameter which specifies whether the type of operation e.g. for an `INSERT` trigger you might use

```
CREATE TRIGGER db_insert
BEFORE INSERT ON db
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    CALL db_trigger_proc('INSERT');
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you can't.

You can see that the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-trigger.html) states that you can use only one event to fire the trigger.

Syntax:

> trigger_event: { INSERT | UPDATE | DELETE }

that means you can choose only one event as a trigger_event.

another argument on the same doc :

> There cannot be multiple triggers for a given table that have the same trigger event and action time. For example, you cannot have two BEFORE UPDATE triggers for a table. But you can have a BEFORE UPDATE and a BEFORE INSERT trigger, or a BEFORE UPDATE and an AFTER UPDATE trigger.